# Formatting using dt.datetime Python

Tags: python, lambda, python-datetime

I'm trying to use `dt.datetime` to split my data by date. However, my date structure is `' date2013-07-04'` [see attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7LwYX.png). Therefore, it doesn't fit with the traditional `'%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f'` format: I've tried re-formatting but I get 2 errors;

1. does not match format
2. redefinition of group name 'd' as group 4; was group 1.

The line of code I have is:

```
x = 'date2013-07-04'
df['Date'] = filename['Date'].apply(lambda x: dt.datetime.strptime(x,'%date%YYYY-%mm-%dd'))
```

Then the errors pull up. Can anyone help? Cheers!

Comment: You can't just _guess_ at the formatters - they're [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes)

Comment: Note that, during my edit, I was very careful to keep the leading whitespace on `' date2013-07-04'`. If that whitespace does exist, then your format string will need to account for it

Comment: There's no difference between the literal string `date` and the literal strings `/`, `:`, or `.` that also occur in the string to parse.

Comment: ah right ok thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The reason it doesn't work is that your format string is invalid, you can find the reference for python's date formatting [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes).

In the meantime you can try this snippet:

```py
import datetime as dt

x = "date2013-07-04"
print(dt.datetime.strptime(x, "date%Y-%m-%d"))
```

It should do it.